# Define vector using other 2 coplanar vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Vectors $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are given. ${\sphericalangle}  (b,c)=2\pi/3.$
Find vector $\vec{a}$, coplanar with $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, length $|\vec{a}|=4$ and ${\sphericalangle}(a,b)=\pi/6$.

I know it's something with triple product. Not sure where that gets me.

EDIT: $|\vec{b}|$=$|\vec{c}|$=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angle between $a$ and $c$ is taken to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$, first find $n=b\times c$ to get the normal to the plane, and then find $c\times n$ to get the direction of $a$. Normalize $a$ and multiply by 4 and that's it.

If the angle between $a$ and $c$ is taken to be $\frac{\pi}{6}$, then $a$ is the angle bisector of $b$ and $-c$, so $a=\frac 12\left(\frac{a}{|a|}-\frac{c}{|c|}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It could be 150° instead of 90°. And you cant find the normal and normalize when vectors aren't given in dimensions?

Comment: I would say, they are possible two angles between a and c:  $\frac{\pi}{2}\,or \,\frac{5\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @georg I have added to my previous answer